# select random columns from a very large dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe in pyspark which has around 150 columns. These columns are obtained from joining different tables. Now my requirement is to write the dataframe to a file but in a specific order like first write 1 to 50 columns then column 90 to 110 and then column 70 and 72. That is I want to select only specific columns along with rearranging them.

I know one one of the way is to use df.select("give your column order") but in my case, the columns are very large and it is not possible to write each and every column name in 'select'.

Please tell me how can I achieve this in pyspark.

Note- I cannot provide any sample data as the number of columns is very large and the column number is the main road blocker in my case.

Comment: not sure why `df.select(list_of_columns) ` is an issue

Comment: Df.select is not an issue but i want to avoid writing more than 100 columns in select. I am looking for a way where I can specify range of columns like 1-50,55and it picks 50 columns and then 55th column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like all that you want to do is to programmatically return the list of column names, pick out some slice or slices from that list, and then select that subset of columns in some order from your dataframe. You can do this by manipulating the list df.columns. As an example:

```
a=[list(range(10)),list(range(1,11)),list(range(2,12))]
df=sqlContext.createDataFrame(a,schema=['col_'+i for i in 'abcdefghij'])
```

df is a dataframe is with columns `['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c', 'col_d', 'col_e', 'col_f', 'col_g', 'col_h', 'col_i', 'col_j']`. You can return that list by calling `df.columns` which you can slice and reorder like you would any other python list. How you do that is up to you and which columns you want to select from the df and in which order. For example:

```
mycolumnlist=df.columns[8:9]+df.columns[0:5]
df[mycolumnlist].show()
```

Returns

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_i|col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d|col_e|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    8|    0|    1|    2|    3|    4|
|    9|    1|    2|    3|    4|    5|
|   10|    2|    3|    4|    5|    6|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create list of columns programmatically

```
first_df.join(second_df, on-'your_condition').select([column_name for column_name in first_df.columns] + [column_name for column_name in second_df.columns])
```

You can select random subset of columns by using `random.sample(first_df.columns, number_of_columns)` function.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This will randomly pick columns rather than what I want it to pick.

Comment: if you know *which* columns you want to pick you can use something like this `[column_name for column_name in first_df.columns if column_name in column_subset]` where `column_subset` is the list of columns you want to select. This might fail if both datasets contain same columns.